# Problems theming UITabBar Items

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, ios8

On app start I change the all my tab bar icon colors to white by setting a white image.
The problem is the more menu button I can't seem to be able to change its gray color when **unselected**.Is there a special way to go about this?
[image]

EDIT:
I tried the following code without success:

```
[((UITabBarItem*)[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4]) setImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_unselected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
[((UITabBarItem*)[self.tabBar.items objectAtIndex:4]) setSelectedImage:[[UIImage imageNamed:@"more_selected"] imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Set the rendering mode of your image like:-

```
self.tabBarItem.selectedImage = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage_selectedImage"]
imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];

self.tabBarItem.image = [[UIImage imageNamed:@"yourImage_image"] 
    imageWithRenderingMode:UIImageRenderingModeAlwaysOriginal];
```

Comment: That is what I do and works fine for every tabBarItem except the more button. Is it impossible to use the default one and change its color? Do I have to have a UIImage for it also?

Comment: I would suggest to use yourImage for this tab also.

Comment: I tried in the mean time and it dis not work either.